# Git - get given range of lines from given file from given branch

Tags: git, git-workflow

I wonder if it's already possible to get given range of lines from given file from given branch in GIT? I'm working on pretty big project, reloading whole solution after switching to a new branch lasts a few seconds, but sometimes I need to see the history / version of current file from e.g. master. Is it possible without switching to master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cat-file` to print the content:

```
git cat-file blob feature/my-feature:./README
```

And then pass to for example `sed` to get the line range:

```
git cat-file ... | sed -n '10,20p'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not that easy to get a specific set of lines from a specific file in a specific revision, but it is *very* easy to get the *entire* file:

```
$ git show rev:path
```

prints it to standard output (which you can then redirect or filter as desired).  The `path` argument is relative to the top level of the tree, regardless of where you are within the work-tree, unless (as in [Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35079693/1256452)) you use `./` at the front.  For instance, to see the 3rd-back version of file dir/README:

```
$ git show HEAD~3:dir/README
```

Note that `git show` bypasses any smudge filter (rather like its low level counterpart, `git cat-file`).